# Highlighting the selected tab using jQueryUI Tabs

Tags: visualforce, javascript, html, tab

I have a header page with links to all the visualforce page as tabs.I need to highlight the tab on select of it.

```
    <apex:page title="{!$Label.site.site_login}" showHeader="false" sidebar="false"       standardStylesheets="false">
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, '/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js')}"  />
  <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, '/js/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js')}"  />
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, '/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.css')}"  />        
 <html lang="en">

<head>

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"> 
$(function() 
{ 
 $( "#tabs" ).tabs(); 
 }); 
</script>  
<style> 
 #tabs .ui-tabs-active 
  { background: red; } 
</style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" style="line-height: 0px; padding: 10px 15px;" href="index.php.html">
                        <img height="30px" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Resources, 'img/logo.png ')}" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse" id="tabs">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li id="Home">
                            <apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.Home}">Home</apex:outputLink>
                        </li>
                        <li id="chatter">
                            <apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.Chatter}">Chatter</apex:outputLink>
                        </li>
                        <li id="page3">
                            <apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.page3}">Room</apex:outputLink>
                        </li>
                        <li id="page4">
                            <apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.page4}">Page4</apex:outputLink>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </body>

    </html>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue and made tab active based on $CurrentPage.Name.Here is my solution

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li id="Home" class="{!IF($CurrentPage.Name == 'Home','active','')}">
                        <apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.Home}">Home</apex:outputLink>
                    </li>
                    <li id="chatter" class="{!IF($CurrentPage.Name == 'Chatter','active','')}">
                        <apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.Chatter}">Chatter</apex:outputLink>
                    </li>
                    <li id="page3" class="{!IF($CurrentPage.Name == 'page3','active','')}">
                        <apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.page3}">Room</apex:outputLink>
                    </li>
                    <li id="page4" class="{!IF($CurrentPage.Name == 'page4','active','')}">
                        <apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.page4}">Page4</apex:outputLink>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 8):

Since you're using jQuery UI tabs, you can style the currently selected tab by applying your styles to the class `ui-tabs-active`.

Comment: Can you please tell me where to put the class ui-tabs-active in visualforce page

Comment: That class is added automatically by jQuery UI to the selected tab.  You can add CSS to that class anywhere you like, for instance:  `.ui-tabs-active { background-color: red; }`

Comment: Do i need to add  <script>
$(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
</script> and <style>
 #tabs .ui-tabs-active {
  background: red;
 }
</style>  to visualforce page

Comment: Yes. That's what initializes the tab interface and sets the style on the active tab class.

Comment: @MarkPond when I added the above script in header I am getting all wierd errors

Comment: I am getting error TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function on browser

Comment: @sf.dev your original question markup was missing the closing `</script>` tag and the `<meta name="author" />` element appears to be malformed. Check your markup as it may be invalid. The error which you are seeing is telling you that the jQuery library could not be loaded and the `$` reference to it does not exist.

Comment: @MarkPond on click tab is not hightlighting.I don't see any error on page.

Comment: Your most recent edit to the question markup now does not include a script reference to jQuery, only to jQueryUI. Do you see any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @MarkPond I updated question and I don't see any errors on browser console

Answer (score 0):

> This is more of an additional comment than an answer (but I need to
>   show some code!)

When using jQuery and Salesforce, it's best to redefine the jQuery "shortcut" $.

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, '/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js')}"  />
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, '/js/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js')}"  />
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, '/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.css')}"  />        

<script>
    /*  Use j$ instead of $ as the jQuery "shortcut"  */    
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();   

    j$(document).ready(function(){
        // onload events

    });

</script>
```

Since you are using jQuery UI tabs, just change the styling of the class `ui-tabs-active` in your `style` section of the `head`.  Whenever a tab is selected, jQuery adds the class `ui-tabs-active` to the HTML element of the Tab.

```
<style>
    .ui-tabs-active{
        background-color:green;
        border:.5rem double white;
        font-size:1rem;
        color:white;
    }


</style>
```

Comment: I have added below script but still active tab is not highlighting  <script>
     $j = jQuery.noConflict();
     function menuClass(id) {
     $j(".active").removeClass("active");
     $j("#"+id).addClass("active");
    }
   </script>  
    <style> 
     #tabs .ui-tabs-active 
      { background: red; } 
    </style>

Comment: I have included <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, '/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js')}"  />
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, '/js/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js')}"  />
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, '/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.css')}"  />

Comment: try this, right click the *active tab* and select `Inspect Element`.  See what the HTML element's id/classes are.  Make sure to use that id/class name in your jQuery